# Some optimization about the code (computing ranks of a vector)?

Tags: c++, c, sorting, optimization

The following code is a function (performance-critical) to compute tied ranks of a vector:

```
//The function here is to compute tied-ranks: answers.com/topic/tied-rank
mergeSort(x,inds,ci);
//mergeSort(): to sort vector x of length ci, also returns keys (inds) of x.

int tj=0;
double xi=x[0];

for (int j = 1; j < ci; ++j)
{
    if (x[j] > xi)
    {
        double rankvalue = 0.5 * (j - 1 + tj);

        for (int k = tj; k < j; ++k)
        {
            ranks[inds[k]] = rankvalue;
        };

        tj = j;
        xi = x[j];
    };      
};

double rankvalue = 0.5 * (ci - 1 + tj);

for (int k = tj; k < ci; ++k)
{
    ranks[inds[k]] = rankvalue;
};
```

The problem is, the supposed performance bottleneck mergeSort(), which is O(NlogN) is several times faster than the other part of codes (which is O(N)), which suggests there is room for huge improvment with the other part of the codes, any advices?

Comment: SO is not a place for code review. Please ask a specific technical question.

Comment: The other part of your code looks like it runs in O(N*N)

Comment: How? it makes at most N adjustments to the data in the vector.

Comment: You could eliminate the loop counter `k` and use `tj` for that. That _might_ shave off one or two nanoseconds if it would avoid a register spill. Seriously, though, it could be locality, after the sort, you use `x`, `inds` and `ranks`, they might push each other out of the cache.

Comment: @user1748356 you have two `for-loops` ignoring the `if` the run-time is [n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1] which is O(n^2). Unless you know how often the 'if statement triggers the worse case run time is O(n^2). You should get some what of a speed up if you eliminate the `if-statement` somehow.

Comment: No, there are < 2*N loop checking, because index of the inner loops are defined by tj and j.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: are there any ways to avoid that cache conflict? the CPU I tested get a 16-way associative L3 cache (core i7).

Comment: Well, I don't even know _if_ you have a cache conflict, it's just speculation. What size are the vectors? It might be faster to first fill `ranks` sequentially, `ranks[k] = rankvalue;` and then "unsort" `ranks` according to `inds`. But it may also not be.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Well, I also suspect there is something to do with cache, as for the vector size, actually `x` is local copy from a large matrix of vectors, and both `x` and `inds` are pre-allocated, fixed address arraies, should be cache-friendly, the typical size of `x` should be ranged from 100-10000 doubles, should be well within the capacity of L3 cache of i7, but I am not sure whether there could be some cache conflicts there, with 16-way associative cache, I suspected the conflicting of memory address should be less likely through.

Comment: With 100-10000, you should even fit comfortably in L2. A merge sort spends most of its time in chunks fitting in L1, so that could explain why it's faster, but I don't see how you could speed up the `rankvalue` noting, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the algorithm has quadratic behavior: if `x[0]` is the largest value in the sequence `tj` stays `0` and you get up to `ci` iterations internally. Did you mean to use `x[inds[0]]` and `x[inds[j]]`?

Comment: No, the mergeSort() takes pointer input, it will change values in x, and x[0] will be the smallest values of vector (original) x, whilst x[ci] being the largest.

Comment: @user1748356 does that not mean that `x[j] > xi` will always be true ?

Comment: @ahenderson: well, not quite: `x[j] == xi` may hold. It seems these are the values affect the desired rank.

Comment: @ahenderson There can be streaks of equal values.

Comment: No, because there are ties, and the exact purpose of the codes there is to adjust ties, see here for tied-ranks:http://www.answers.com/topic/tied-rank